# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' line 7

Tags: php, syntax-error

Please i dont know how to remove this error on line 7 onto this $rest_url = “https://mydomain.com/rest-api/analytics/HTML/”.$login.”/”.$hash.”/”.$timestamp.”.do”;

```
$timestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
$login = ‘username’;
$password = ‘password’;
$hash = md5(md5($password).$timestamp);
$rest_url = “https://mydomain.com/rest-api/analytics/HTML/”.$login.”/”.$hash.”/”.$timestamp.”.do”;
$post_data = array(
‘range’ => ‘LAST_7_DAYS’,
‘groupBy’ => ‘PLACEMENT’
);

/* Options of HTTP request; http key should be used when posting to https url */
$options = array(
‘http’ => array(
‘header’ => “Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n”,
‘method’ => ‘POST’,
‘content’ => http_build_query($post_data)
)
);

/* Actual call to REST URL */
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($rest_url, false, $context);
echo($result);
```

Comment: Your quotes look weird

Comment: Those are not quotes. `Apostrophes` ;)

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Word or OpenOffice Writer as text editor? I suggest you don't.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario good point... this is probably because of some autocorrection function... better to use simple `Notepad` than `Word`. I like `EditPlus` that highlights syntax.

Comment: i use notepad ++ but still waiting for correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string starting and ending characters are incorrect.

You are using `‘` and `“` ... replace them with `'` and `"` to make your code valid.

Comment: i have replaced ‘ and “ with  ' and " in all code but its not working

Comment: starting string now set but it show more error after that syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' on 15 here ‘header’ => “Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n”,

Comment: Still the same `“` instead of `"`

Comment: after thats i did same replacement with Content-type but now get another error online 23 Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request here $result = file_get_contents($rest_url, false, $context);

Comment: I think it may be related to SSL routines. Try changing `https:` to `ssl:` and adding a port `443` after host. That is a blind guess, may not help. Generally it is what it says. It's not a PHP syntax error, but server response. Does server support https at all?

Comment: And check if your `php_openssl` extension is on.

Comment: Thanks @Flash Thunder is got my final correct code with you support and well thanks to all who participated in this ask

Answer (score 0):

since `file_get_contents()` is not reliable in remote connections,

You have to use CURL to overcome this http error.

For more info on curl_init read [this](https://www.php.net/curl_init)